# Violation of Primary Key when trying to add entity with foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 with a code first approach.

I'm trying to do a testing system. It has five classes with one-to-one and one-to-many relationships. One Test has one TestInfo, one User has many TestResults, one TestResult has one TestInfo and many QuestionResults. Here they are (without some simple value-type properties):

```
public class TestInfo
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int TestId { get; set; }
    public virtual TestInfo Info { get; set; }
    //some other stuff
    //...
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }

    List<TestResult> _results = new List<TestResult>();
    public virtual List<TestResult> Results
    {
        get { return _results; }
        set { _results = value; }
    }
    //...
}

public class TestResult
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int TestResultId { get; set; }
    public virtual TestInfo TestInfo { get; set; }
    //...

    private List<QuestionResult> _questionResults = new List<QuestionResult>();
    public virtual List<QuestionResult> QuestionResults
    {
        get { return _questionResults; }
        set { _questionResults = value; }
    }
}

public class QuestionResult
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int QuestionResultId { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

My context:

```
class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add new TestResult to existing User for existing Test (TestInfo is the same):

```
public void AddTestResult(TestResult result)
{
    User user = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Results).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == _currentLogin);
    TestInfo existingTestInfo = _context.Tests.Where(t => t.Info.Name == result.TestInfo.Name).FirstOrDefault().Info;
    result.TestInfo = existingTestInfo;
    user.Results.Add(result);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I'm doing it this way, EF throws an exception:

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.TestInfoes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TestInfoes'. The duplicate key value is (First test).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

If I remove QuestionResults property from TestResult class, all works fine. It seems strange for me.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Swap these two lines:

```
user.Results.Add(result);
result.TestInfo = existingTestInfo;
```

`user.Results.Add(result)` marks the whole object graph as `Added`.

Comment: Is `result` a new result, or existing, with existing QuestionResults?

Comment: And does table `TestResults` have an auto-incrementing primary key (identity column)?

Comment: Yes, result is a new entity, with new QuestionResults.<br/>TestResult entity has key property int TestResultId with autoincrement, like other entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TestInfo existingTestInfo = _context.Tests.Where(t => t.Info.Name == result.TestInfo.Name).Include(i => i.TestInfos).FirstOrDefault().Info;
```

I also got this error until I included the child table then everything worked ok.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem when using the EF5 framework in a separate data access layer (DAL).  To fix it, I had to iterate through the foreign key classes and re-attach them.  I suspect there's a better way, but this got me past the post.

```
if (db.Entry(result.TestInfo).State == EntityState.Detached)
    db.Entry(result.TestInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Let me know if this helps!